# rounded y in unicode fonts

Tags: fonts, unicode

I am searching for fonts which give in math mode this result:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

I use LuaLaTex, so the first example (the one I want) was obtained by (with the latin modern font by default):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    $x+y$
\end{document}
```

I am searching other fonts which do the same thing.

Comment: Concmath and Garamond have comparatively rounded corners for x and y. The design for concmath (concrete) is very similar to  but thicker

Comment: Thank you @ApoorvPotnis. I’ll check that

Answer (score 1):

And why don't you use the LM-math if you like it??

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}
    $x+y$

\setmathfont{texgyrebonum-math.otf}[Scale=0.9]
    $x+y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I never said I liked it. But I want this kind of "y" and I would like to have more choices