# Changing unicode font for just one symbol

Tags: symbols, unicode

I am trying to get the "Bourbaki" symbol (dangerous bend U+2621).
I use latin modern font which doesn't have this symbol, so I tried this (changing the font in STIX):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}

    \usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
    
    \NewDocumentCommand{\bourbaki}{}{{\setmainfont{STIX two Text}\symbol{"2621}}}
    
    
    \begin{document}
        \bourbaki
    \end{document}
```

It doesn't work because in the log file, I get:
Missing character: There is no ☡ (U+2621) in font STIXtwoText:mode=node;script
=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;!

How could I get the symbol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, STIX Two Text doesn't have the glyph, but STIX Two Math has it.

Since there is no law that requires math fonts to be exclusively used for math, you just define a suitable font face.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

\usepackage[
  warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},
  math-style=french
]{unicode-math}

\newfontface{\STIXTWO}{STIX Two Math}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bourbaki}{}{\mbox{\STIXTWO\symbol{"2621}}}

\begin{document}

\bourbaki

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I use Latin modern font because I want rounded x and y in maths mode (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689860/rounded-y-in-unicode-fonts/689861#689861) and I don’t know any other font which does that

Comment: @Didier The code I showed will select Latin Modern Math, because it's the default for `unicode-math`.

Comment: Thank you again. I dare asking another question. I am looking for Unicode fonts with rounded x and y in maths mode (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689860/rounded-y-in-unicode-fonts/689861#689861). Is there a website which regroups fonts and where I could find these kind of fonts

Comment: @Didier Use Latin Modern, if you like the font. I found nothing special in the shape of single letters, so long as they're distinguishable from one another.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. In fact, I find the characters a little too thin (compared to Erewhon for instance) but it will be okay

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[version=stx,range="2621]{STIX2Math.otf}

\newcommand\bourbaki{{\mathversion{stx}\ensuremath{\symbol{"2621}}}}

\begin{document}
foo \bourbaki\  bar $\bourbaki$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ user187802 Thank you

Comment: You get warnings “Command `\mathversion` invalid in math mode”. There's no need to define a math version.

Answer (score 0):

The New Computer Modern Math fonts have the "Bourbaki" symbol (dangerous bend U+2621) matching the Computer Modern style.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket},math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bourbaki}{}{\danger}


\begin{document}
    \(\bourbaki\)
\end{document}
```

[image: bourbaki dangerous bend U+2621 new computer modern math book]